R Package for Displaying Two-Way ANOVA with Mean, SE, and Significance Letters (Both Capital and Small Letters)
I am looking for an R package that can help me display the results of a two-way ANOVA. Specifically, I need to include the following elements in my output:
Mean values ( not estimated, originial)
Standard Errors (SE) ( not estimated, originial)
Significance indicated with letters, using both capital and small letters (e.g., 'A', 'a', 'B', 'b')
fit <- aov(log(response) ~ treatments(4 levels) * species(4 types), data = sample_data)
tukeyHSD(fit)
the table should look like
enter image description here
The capital letters are comparing species column wise and small letters comparing treatments.
Is there an R package that provides this functionality, or any combination of functions/packages that can help me achieve this? The interaction is non significant so interactions should be removed?
Emmeans gives only estimated mean, MultcompView only gives small letters (may be I am wrong) and the final table is too many letters.

You can achieve your desired output with a more concise approach by focusing on the essential steps. Here's a streamlined version of the process:
To perform the Two-Way ANOVA:
fit <- aov(log(response) ~ treatments * species, data = sample_data)

Using 'emmeans' to Get Estimated Marginal Means and Perform Pairwise Comparisons:
library(emmeans)
emm <- emmeans(fit, ~ treatments + species)

Generate Letters for Significance with multcompView:
library(multcompView)
tukey_letters <- cld(emm, Letters = letters)

Combine Results into a Final Table:
final_table <- data.frame(
  Treatment = tukey_letters$treatments,
  Species = tukey_letters$species,
  Mean = summary(emm)$emmean,
  SE = summary(emm)$SE,
  Letters = tukey_letters$.group
)

print(final_table)


Thanks, should i report estimated marginal means or originial groupwise means? more over the final table is not the same as I wanted. I already have the table that you created. please have a look at the picture I uploaded in my originial question of what I meant. Moreover, cld is a function of multcomp package, not multcompView package

you need to combine the original means, standard errors, and significance letters for each species under each treatment.

@sta_107 could you please mark the answer so it might help other people as well
